# How to show there are infinite solution to a given Pell's equation?

Tags: proof-writing, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

I was asked to prove the Pell's equation
$$x^2-7y^2=1$$
has infinitely many solution. Here is what I did

By using Brahmagupta method we can generate infinitely many integer solutions. Is that supposed to be a proof? If not could you show me how can I prove this formally?

Comment: If you did show this, you are finished. The more modern version uses powers of $8+3\sqrt{7}$.

Comment: see for example here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation

Answer (score 1):

Equation:

$$x^2-7y^2=1$$

Using the first solution: $(x_1 ; y_1) - (8;3)$

You can find the rest of them.

$$x_{n + 1} = 8 x_n + 21 y_n$$

$$y_{n + 1} = 3 x_n +  8 y_n$$